# Faking flash plugin info in phantomjs 1.8

Tags: flash, plugins, phantomjs

I'm a newbie to PhantomJs. I'm using 1.8.1 version. I've looked at [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/8pCA0x2evH8/l8CTff6y53MJ) to solve this as i've similar requirement.

I'm doing something like this:

```
page.onInitialized = function () {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        (function () {
            window.navigator.plugins = {
                'length': 1, 
                'Shockwave Flash': {
                    'description':'fakeflash'
                }
            };
        })();
    });
};
```

When i do console.log (window.navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'].description)

I get undefined as the result.

Could anyone tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enable plugin loading with --load-plugins=yes option ?

Comment: Thank you for response. There is no flash plugin support available in this version.. it was discontinued from version 1.5.

Comment: There is a working phantomJS 1.10 version with flash support: https://github.com/jantimon/phantom-flash-vagrant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the entire `navigator` object (you can't just modify some properties).

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.onInitialized = function () {
    page.evaluate(function () {
        window.navigator = {
            plugins: {
                length: 1,
                'Shockwave Flash': {
                    description: 'fakeflash'
                }
            }
        };
    });
};

page.content = '<html><body>Hello</body></html>';
page.evaluate(function () {
    console.log(window.navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'].description);
});

phantom.exit();
```