# Fake plugin support in CasperJs, by replacing window.navigator plugins object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, casperjs, navigator

When i try to fake Shockwave Flash support in CasperJS as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587849/1365141(but with PhantomJs, its won't work. 
What i doing wrong?

```
casper.on 'page.initialized', ->
  casper.evaluate ->
    window.navigator =
      plugins:
        length: 1
        "Shockwave Flash":
          description: "Flsh 123"
  @echo "Shockwafe Flahs #{window.navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'].description}"
```

Answer (score 1):

As we say in Russia, before drinking vodka with a bear with balalaika:

«Correctly formulated question — half of answer.»(©Russians)

```
casper.on 'page.initialized', ->
  window.navigator =
    plugins:
      length: 1
      "Shockwave Flash":
        description: "Flsh 123"
  @echo "Shockwafe Flahs #{window.navigator.plugins['Shockwave Flash'].description}"
```

And you ask:

— What is the difference?

I will answer to you:

— The difference in context.

When you use casper.evaluate, you use page context.

Comment: So in other words, you can't fake plugin support when using phantomJS?